# How to cite an article from Arxiv using biblatex with bibstyle=phys?

Tags: biblatex, arxiv

I like to cite an article which is on arXiv like so

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{library.bib}
@article{Springer2016,
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
arxivId = {1602.02972},
author = {Springer, P. and Koch, S. W. and Kira, M.},
eprint = {1602.02972},
title = {{Excitonic terahertz absorption in semiconductors with effective-mass anisotropies}},
url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.02972},
year = {2016}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[
    style=numeric-comp,
    bibstyle=phys,
    articletitle=false,
    biblabel=brackets,
    backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{Springer2016}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This will produce a rather useless output with just stating the names and the year. Is there a way to print some arXiv related info to the library?

Comment: What does REVTeX do here? (I use that as a reference for physics BibTeX handling, being a chemist myself.)

Comment: @JosephWright Using REVTex, the entry additionally includes a state at the end reading: arXiv:1602.02972. The number is the eprint number.

Comment: Note that arXiv articles that have not been published in a journal are probably better classed as `@online` (for `@article`s the `journal` is mandatory), cf. `biblatex-examples.bib`'s `wassenberg`, `baez/online` and `itzhaki`. To get proper arXiv support you will want to use `@online{Springer2016,
  author       = {Springer, P. and Koch, S. W. and Kira, M.},
  eprinttype   = {arxiv},
  eprint       = {1602.02972},
  eprintclass  = {cond-mat.mtrl-sci},
  title        = {Excitonic terahertz absorption in semiconductors with effective-mass anisotropies},
  year         = {2016},
}`

Comment: @moewe I was wondering about that myself: coming from an area without preprints I see them as distinct from journal articles.

Comment: @JosephWright My main objection with having (arXiv) preprints as `@article` is that they are missing the `journal(title)` and thus leave a the "in:" with styles that print it. Since the document is available online, `@online` seems a logical choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current settings in the `phys` style turn off printing of DOIs, eprints and so on by default, so you need to set `eprint=true` when loading the style. I might revise that for eprints as they are rather common in physics (the settings are inherited from the chemistry styles I've created, where such things are much rarer).

Comment: Unfortunately, `eprint=true` prints the arxiv information for all articles, not just the ones that don't have a journal reference yet. This is not what is usually seen in journals. Would it be possible to only print the eprint information if there is no journal reference? Most people get their bibliographies for example from [adsabs](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/) and it would be very tiresome to edit every single entry that one gets from there.